# OnClick button working only after second time Asp.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to web development and right now I'm working on a website. I have a problem with a Save button on an ASP.Net (front end) web form (back end is in C#). The button is supposed to save data entered in a textbox to a database.

When the Save button is clicked the first time, the page just 'reloads' and clear the textbox and nothing is saved in the SQL Server database (dbo connection). Then when I click the same 'Save' button a second time after re-entering information in the textbox, it actually saves to the database and goes back to a main menu page (as expected). And if I try to re-enter different information, the save button will be working just fine.

The problem happens when a user logs in and navigate to the page where he enters the data and saves it. It will never ever work the first time.

Unfortunately because of confidential purposes, I have to omit and rename  certain file paths/directories and tables name!

Here's my Asp.NET code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" debug="True" Inherits="Default" src="Default.cs"      AutoEventWireup ="true"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ob" TagName="ComboTree"  Src="/obout/Combotree/ComboTree.ascx" %>
<%@ Reference Control="/obout/Combotree/ComboTree.ascx" %>

<HTML>

<HEAD>
<!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->

</HEAD>

<BODY >
<FORM runat="server">
  <BASEFONT face="Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif" color=black size=2>
    <TABLE height="100%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="780" align=Center border=0>
      <!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->
      <TR VALIGN="top">
      <!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->
   `enter code here`<TD vAlign=top width="100%" HEIGHT="100%">
   <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0 HEIGHT="100%">
   <!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->  
   <TR>
      <!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->  
      <TD vAlign=top align=left >
      <!--- START YOUR CODE HERE!!!!! --->
      <script>
        function disableListItems(checkBoxListId, disable)
        {
            // Get the checkboxlist object.
            ctr = 0;
            while(1 == 1)
            {
                checkbox = document.getElementById(checkBoxListId + "_" + ctr);
                if(checkbox == null)
                {        
                    return;
                }
                checkbox.checked = true;
                checkbox.disabled = disable;
                ctr++;
            }

        }         

        function checkForm()
        {
            var errMsg = "";
            if(isBlank(document.getElementById("tbName").value))
            {
                errMsg += "\n-Folder Name";
            }

            if(errMsg!="")
            {
                alert("The following fields cannot be left blank." + errMsg);
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
      </script>
      <font Class="heading">File Library - <ASP:Label ID="lbTitle" RunAt="Server"/> Folder</font>
        <INPUT Type="Hidden" ID="hdFolderID" RunAt="Server"/>
        <INPUT Type="Hidden" ID="hdParentFolderID" RunAt="Server"/>
        <TABLE CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%" >
        <TR>
            <TD ColSpan="2" Class="spreadsheet_line">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><B>Name</B></TD>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet" Width="100%"><ASP:TextBox ID="tbName" Columns="34" RunAt="Server"/></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR VAlign="Top" Visible="False" RunAt="Server">
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet" NOWRAP><B>Description</B></TD>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><ASP:TextBox ID="tbDescription" TextMode="Multiline" Cols="25" Rows="5" RunAt="Server"/></TD>
        </TR>           
        <TR>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><B>Active?</B></TD>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><ASP:CheckBox ID="cbActive" RunAt="Server"/></TD>
        </TR>           
        <TR Visible="False" RunAt="Server">
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><B>Folder</B></TD>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><ob:ComboTree id="ctFolders" runat="server"/></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR VAlign="Top" ID="trLicensees" RunAt="Server">
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><B>Departments</B></TD>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet">
                <ASP:DropDownList ID="ddLicensee" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="DepartmentId" RunAt="Server"/>
                <ASP:CheckBox ID="cbAll" Text="All" RunAt="Server"/>
                <div style="text-align: left; width: 30%; margin-left:-3px">
                    <ASP:CheckBoxList ID="cblLicensees" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="DepartmentId" style="background-color:F3F3F3" RunAt="Server"/> <!--**-->
                </div>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD Class="Spreadsheet" Align="Right" ColSpan="2">
                <ASP:ImageButton ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" ImageUrl="/images/buttons/btnSave.gif" RunAt="Server"/>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
      <!--- END YOUR CODE HERE!!!!! --->
      </TD>
      <!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->  
   </TR>
   <!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->  
  </TABLE>
</TD>
<!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->  
</TR>
<!-- #INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/.../" -->  
</TABLE>
</BASEFONT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And here's the (back end) code for the Save button written in C#:

```
    public void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs E){    
    int counter = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["counter"].Value);
    counter++;
    Response.Cookies["counter"].Value = counter.ToString();

    try{
    SqlConnection Conn = GetConnection();
    string SQL;
    SqlCommand Cmd;
    SqlDataReader Dtr;

        if(hdFileID.Value=="")
        {
            Response.Write("Executing Save (adding new folder to DB");
            SQL = "EXEC sp_File_Add @Name,@Description,@UserID";
            Response.Write("Save successfully executed. Added to DB");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Executing Save (saving info of folder to DB");
            SQL = "EXEC sp_File_Update @Name,@Description,@UserID,@FileID";
            Response.Write("Save successfully executed. Saved to DB");
        }




        Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL,Conn);

        Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        Cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = tbName.Text;

        Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", SqlDbType.Text));
        Cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = tbDescription.Text;

        Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int));
        Cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(hdUserID_Global.Value);

        if(hdFileID.Value!="")
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileID", SqlDbType.Int));
            Cmd.Parameters["@FileID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(hdFolderID.Value);
        }

        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if(hdFileID.Value=="")
        {
            SQL = "SELECT MAX(FileID) AS FileID FROM tbl_File WHERE CreatedByUserID=@UserID";
            Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL,Conn);

            Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int));
            Cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(hdUserID_Global.Value);

            Dtr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(Dtr.Read())
            {
                hdFileID.Value = Dtr["FileID"].ToString();
            }
            Dtr.Close();
        }

        SQL = "DELETE FROM tbl_FileLicense ";
        SQL += " WHERE FileID=@FileID ";

        Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL,Conn);

        Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileID", SqlDbType.Int));
        Cmd.Parameters["@FileID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(hdFileID.Value.ToString());

        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if(ddLicense.Visible)
        {
            SQL = "EXEC sp_doc_Folder_Add @FileID,@LicenseID,@UserID";
            Response.Write("Save successfully executed. Added to DB");
            Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL,Conn);

            Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FolderID", SqlDbType.Int));
            Cmd.Parameters["@FileID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(hdFileID.Value.ToString());

            Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LicenseID", SqlDbType.Int));
            Cmd.Parameters["@LicenseID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddLicense.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());

            Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int));
            Cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(hdUserID_Global.Value);

            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
        }

        Conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("/Library/Default2.aspx?FileID=" + Request["RootFileID"].ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Response.Write("An error occurred while saving: " + e);
        Response.End();
    }

}
```

I've been struggling for more than 2 days on that and I don't see why the button is not firing the first time but only as from the 2nd time. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try to debug and see which event got fired the 1st button click, I suspect it is the Page_Load event

Comment: In first line of webform.aspx i.e. <%@ Page Language="C#" add this attribute and see if it works. EnableEventValidation="false". Also check if the flow of code by setting up breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by adding `EnableViewState = False` in the `<FORM runat="server">` tag in the asp.NET code

Answer (score 0):

You should open connection i.e `Conn.open()` before executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` method.

Try this, if it still doesn't work, in first line of `webform.aspx` i.e. `<%@ Page Language="C#"` add this attribute and see if it works: `EnableEventValidation="false"`. Also check the flow of code by setting breakpoints.

Comment: Tried both but it's unfortunately still not working. Any other suggestions please?